# Floating Action Button in wrong position

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I have Floating Action Buttons in two of my Fragment layouts and sometimes they move to the wrong position, altough I use CoordinatorLayout.

[This is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmXwx.png)

[This is how it somtetimes look when i open the Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVvdw.png)

This is the code of my fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/notes_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.NotesFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/notes_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/new_note_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_48dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/notes_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    android:onClick="openNewNote"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Does anyone have an idea why the FAB sometimes move to the wrong position?

Comment: as per your xml  there is recycler view but screenshot shows textview?

Comment: @Sangram the textview is an ViewHolder. It is shown when the recycler view is empty.

Comment: you can also set gravity programatically to FAB.check my answer.

Comment: @Cimoe did you fix this issue I am facing same issue

Comment: put FAB to the first child is solves the issue (with v25)

Comment: good question. Also experiencing this problem :( I have a very similar layout and moving the FAB to be the first child is not possible, how would the layout_anchor attribute work as its now before the LinearLayout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. The problem is with the combination of `app:layout_anchor` and `com.android.support.design:24.2.0+`

I was able to fix this issue by either removing the `app:layout_anchor` property from the fab or by reverting to an older version of the design library. `24.1.1` worked fine for me. I also had to revert my `appcompat v7` library to `24.1.1`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can confirm the same issue, I was able to resolve by removing the app:layout_anchor

Answer (score 6):

Try to make `FAB` first child of `CoordinatorLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            .../>

       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
             .../>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I have a very similar layout and moving the FAB to be the first child is not possible, how would the layout_anchor attribute work as its now before the LinearLayout?

Comment: layout_anchor should work anyway, no matter if it above or below anchored view. The only restriction is that parent of view which has layout_anchor attribute should be a CoordinatorLayout

Comment: as I just noticed with API19 the button appears behind the next child item

Comment: It's strange but it works even 24.2.0+. Only one downside - anchor and gravity should be set programmatically.

Comment: Ok, I found real downside - in oldest devices if you have match_parent clickable view after fab, this view will handle clicks, so there is no way to click on fab

Answer (score 2):

The `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams` class has the `anchorGravity` field for that. For example:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
lp.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | GravityCompat.START;
fab.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it is still not working. The fab is still moving randomly to the wrong position

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was a bug in support library from 24.2.0 and above. So, the only way to workaround it was to build the app with support lib v24.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
             android:id="@+id/rvToDoList"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

      </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

       <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/rvToDoList"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these suggestions ended up working for me (downgrading was not an option; moving the FAB up so it's the first child makes it invisible on Android 14; removing layout_anchor makes it jump to a random position all the time)

I instead used ConstraintLayout to position the FAB manually between the two views I wanted it at. Since the entire screen of mine has no scrolling area, that worked fine.

To position the FAB this way, set both its top and bottom constraint to the bottom of one of the upper view it's supposed  to overlap and make sure it is the last child in the ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Put the FAB inside a RelativeLayout, it worked for me, I am using the version 25.3.1 of the support library